# Downgrade iOS Project Deployment Target from 8 to 7

Tags: ios, core-data, ios8, xcode6

i'm searching how to downgrade my sdk version of iOS from 8 to 7 since the access to Core Data have changed

i was previously using

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
User *user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
```

But it's no longer working any idea how to downgrade to ios 7 or to use core data now ?

Thx

Comment: What "isn't working" ?  There is no change to accessing a property from an app delegate (which is what you are doing here).  What is the error?

Comment: To debug your core data access you have to check whether the managed object context has been correctly initialized first. This code snippet does not allow to see this step. Furthermore, could you tell us if you get any error through the error variable?

Comment: it seems that the NSEntityDescription does no longer exist 
xCode ask me to replace it with kSecAttrDescription

Comment: No change in the new SDK at this level. Perhaps you have another error in your code which causes Xcode not to recognize the NSEntityDescription identifier. Could you edit your question adding your code around the snippet you provide above?

Comment: Who said NSEntityDescription doesnt exist with Xcode 6?

Answer (score 1):

In order strictly to answer to the question in the title of this topic, you can come back to the previous iOS SDK by continuing to use Xcode 5 instead of Xcode 6. Both Xcode versions can be installed at the same time.
Simply rename the Xcode 5 directory before to install Xcode 6.

But according to your issue this one can only be to get your app working again shortly. No doubt you will have to solve your Core Data issue under iOS 8 soon.

Answer (score 0):

Changing deployment target will only restrict the app to run on iOS8.
You just use Xcode 5.x, that does not have iOS8.x SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading SDK is no longer possible due to Xcode 5 no longer being available in Mac App Store.
You can only install Xcode 6 from now on.

Comment: You can get older versions from outside of the app store if you have a developer account.

Comment: Yep, just saw now that you mentioned :D Didn't know that ! Thanks for the update!